# Can ambient humidity significantly affect the texture of pastry doughs?

Tags: dough

There was some discussion on [this question about dry, crumbly shortcrust dough](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75789/1672) about whether ambient humidity could cause a normally good shortcrust recipe to come out dry and crumbly.

Is this possible? How strong of an effect might be expected from going from "average" humidity to extremely dry? Would it affect all types of pastry dough similarly?